# How to make phpmyadmin work without 404 error?

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I have started xampp and mysql and http://127.0.0.1:8000/phpmyadmin throws me an 404 error.
I tried with stackoverflow solutions and things like that:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

Comment: FYI: I removed the "Laravel" tag since your question is about XAMPP and PHPMyAdmin, not Laravel.

Comment: 404 error means the url cannot be found on the server.

Comment: Looks like php is not properly installed or configured on your localhost.  You may want to ping the IP address, to be sure it isn't problem with your machine, operating system or firewall blocking inbound requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about the Port 8000? xampp on default settings starts on port 80, try http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin or http://localhost/phpmyadmin. Does a page show up when you enter just http://localhost?

Comment: None of links are working, with http://localhost there is also 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

I had to start apache and use port 80 to make it works, thanks for help.